# Why program with php frameworks if it can be done better with ruby on rails, python or java?

Tags: java, php, python, ruby-on-rails, django

We have discussion in my job place about question (We use 1 of the php frameworks):
Why program with php frameworks big web application if it can be done better with **ruby on rails, python or java**? 
Please say our opinion
thanks

Comment: The real question is why *you* are doing it.  Only you, your coworkers and your bosses can answer that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only know PHP and you don't feel like learning Ruby/Python/Java. Seriously, if it *can* be done better with another tool, it *should* be done with another tool. Of course, this assumes the other tools are actually better. That part is arguable. Some people are so stuck up on their "my way is the best way" that they leave out the "because it's the only way I know" part.

Answer (score 2):

"Better" is subjective. Does Rails have such a strong background & community full of tools like [opcode cachers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_PHP_Cache), [memcache](http://www.memcached.org/) libs, [PINBA](http://pinba.org/), [PHPFpm](http://php-fpm.org/) and many many more?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. It depends on your needs. If rails meets all your needs, then you should go for it. If you need to take advantage of the extended community of PHP, then that's what you should go for. It's all about choosing the best tool for the job. i.e., "better" is not only subjective, but it varies from task to task.

Comment: The whole question is subjective.

Comment: Agree with every your point, @Mark. I just wanted to advocate PHP a bit, to make a balance. Though to compare a PHP frameworks with Rails/Django would be interesting.